# unable to configure phpstorm 9 debug on mac

Tags: phpstorm

I am trying to configure phpstorm debug. My php files from my remote server which is on example.com have `GET` calls and its not working .I have installed chrome extension but when I try to debug php on chrome .Nothing happens. The path where phpstorm in `local/bin/php` and xdebug is installed in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.5`  . Under Interpreters `/usr/bin/php` : `php version  is 5.5.27` and `debugger is not installed`.But when I enter  `php --version` in terminal I get :

```
Zend Engine v2.5.0,
    with Xdebug v2.3.3,
```

I have installed MAMP pro and have added `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php` in PHP Interpreter .I can see xdebug 2.2.4 .But I would like to debug single php on server not php-webapp. How can I do that?

I am trying to configure it for more than a day but it's not working.I really appreciate any help.

Comment: This most likely means that you have more than 1 PHP installations on your computer and IDE uses different one to what you get in terminal. I suggest checking `which php` (or maybe it's `where php` -- not sure, not a Mac user myself) in both actual terminal and PhpStorm built-in terminal.

Comment: As for actual debugging process: **1)** https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm **2)** https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/quickstart/debugger.html

Comment: when i click on debug it creates php script under that it has the php file and configuration has only the file path and name and the rest of the fields like arguments,command line options and interpreters are blank.When debug proceeds till mysql_connect it gives connection error and its trying to connect to local mysql.I don't know why? How can I debug. I tried to add config under php remote debug and I have no idea what to add under absolute path.I tried http://www.example.com and tried load the php on chrome again which has xdebug-helper as addon with debug turned green and it loads normally

Comment: It loads normally but it does trigger debug on phpstorm.How can I get debug to work.Also why is mysql trying to connec to local in the previous scenario.